# Asterisks in the Noam Elimelech

Tags: chasidut-hasidism

In the sefer Noam Elimelech, many of his Torah pieces have shorter pieces within them that have a few asterisks before and after the piece. What is the significance of these markings?

Comment: can you link to an example: http://hebrewbooks.org/38141

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're referring to specifically; are you talking about dots between paragraphs? That may be just delineating separate pieces.

On the other hand, in the earliest editions of the text there are asterisks embedded *within* the text - those follow seemingly fragmented statements and comments. According to Rav Tal Moshe Zwecker:

> In the original printing of Noam Elimelech there were stars or asterisks
>   found throughout the passages. Tradition has it that these stars have some
>   meaning. In the sefer Devarim Areivim,25 it is written: “In the first edition of
>   the sefer, there are in many places small stars which allude to some secret
>   meaning.” I also heard in the name of the Klausenberger that in the heavens
>   above (possibly meaning the stars themselves) there are thousands of “commentaries”
>   on the small stars found in the work Noam Elimelech. I have
>   therefore included those stars wherever they appear in the original text.

(His translation in free PDF can be found [here](https://torahdownloads.com/assets/material/Mipeninei%20Noam%20Elimelech%20-%20Translation%20of%20Sefer%20Noam%20Elimelech.pdf) ).

The *Noam Elimelech* is a deep, mystical text on the Torah; in Hasidic lore, it is one of three essential books, along with the *Tanya* and *Likkutei MoHaran*. They are referred to respectively as the *Sefer Tzaddikim* the *Sefer Beinonim* and the *Sefer Reshaim* (unattributed quote; although I heard it from Rav Moshe Weinberger and others).

Comment: I would like to +1 because I always wondered about those asterisks, which are reproduced in the edition I use, but I don't think they are what the question is talking about. . . although only @Mark A. can say for sure.

Comment: very good. I also heard some explanations but without sources

Comment: Yes, I was referring to those asterisks that Shmuel Brown refers to. I had heard that it has some mysterious connotations but I was wondering if there's any more info about it. Thanks for the extra info and sources.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard numerous times that in Chasidic tradition the stars in the sefer represent a time when R' Elimelech had an עליית נשמה while saying over the teachings and came bac down to to physicality.